# How to submit the form in stepper

Tags: reactjs, forms, redux, material-ui, submit

I am trying to submit my form on material ui's stepper form. For more information about it: https://material-ui.com/components/steppers/

Anyway, in my checkout page, I defined the material ui stepper and it has different kind of components which have their own form.

```
  function getStepContent(step, props) {
      
      switch (step) {
        case 0:
          return <Component1 {...props} />;
        case 1:
          return <Component2 {...props}/>;
        case 2:
        default:
          return "Unknown step";
      }
    }
```

For example, component1 has its own form and when you click next you go to component2 which has a different kind of form. Component2's form is created with the information coming from Component1's form that's why I need to submit the form before I go to the next. But since I need to submit the form inside the component I am really confused. And of course, I tried to add type="submit" to the Next button but didn't affect anything.

So basically here also, the stepper is defined how to go to the next steps:

```
<Container>
        <div className={classes.root}>
          <Stepper activeStep={activeStep} orientation="vertical">
            {steps.map((label, index) => (
              <Step key={label}>
                <StepLabel>{label}</StepLabel>
                <StepContent>
                  <Typography>{getStepContent(index, {checkoutForm, handleChange})}</Typography>
                  <div className={classes.actionsContainer}>
                    <div>
                      <Button
                        disabled={activeStep === 0}
                        onClick={handleBack}
                        className={classes.button}
                      >
                        Back
                      </Button>
                      <Button
                        variant="contained"
                        color="primary"
                        onClick={handleNext}
                        className={classes.button}
                      >
                        {activeStep === steps.length - 1 ? "Finish" : "Next"}
                      </Button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </StepContent>
              </Step>
            ))}
          </Stepper>
        </div>
      </Container>
```

So I think I have to do something to submit the form of the component in here:

```
const handleNext = () => {
    setActiveStep((prevActiveStep) => prevActiveStep + 1);
  };
```

So I am waiting for your answers.
Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to submit the form with a button outside the form then the button needs the form attribute with the id of the form

```
<button type="submit" form={`form-step${activeStep}`} value="Submit">Submit</button>
```

then the function you passed to the form onSubmit will be executed. So you could pass the handleNext to the form and make sure the form id matches the form attribute off the button

for example for the form in component 1
create a handleFormSubmit function. then do something with the formdata before you change the activeStep

```
const handleFormSubmit = () => {
  // do something with form data
  props.handleNext()
} 

<form id="form-step1" onSubmit={handleFormSubmit}></form>
```

your example with my changes

```
<Container>
        <div className={classes.root}>
          <Stepper activeStep={activeStep} orientation="vertical">
            {steps.map((label, index) => (
              <Step key={label}>
                <StepLabel>{label}</StepLabel>
                <StepContent>
// pass handleNext to getStepContent here
                  <Typography>{getStepContent(index, {checkoutForm, handleChange, handleNext})}</Typography>
                  <div className={classes.actionsContainer}>
                    <div>
                      <Button
                        disabled={activeStep === 0}
                        onClick={handleBack}
                        className={classes.button}
                      >
                        Back
                      </Button>
                      <Button
                        variant="contained"
                        color="primary"
// set type submit and form here
                        type="submit"
                        form={`form-step${activeStep}`}
                        className={classes.button}
                      >
                        {activeStep === steps.length - 1 ? "Finish" : "Next"}
                      </Button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </StepContent>
              </Step>
            ))}
          </Stepper>
        </div>
      </Container>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But the problem is handleNext is on the checkout page and I am submitting the form in the component

Comment: @Themaninthepinksuit I don't think it matters. you can submit any form with the button in the stepContent. You can define any function you want in the forms. Just make sure you pass the update function or setActiveStep as a prop to your components, so you could pass handleNext. And then in your form const handleFormSubmit = () => { // do something with formdata , props.handleNext() }

Comment: Sorry but I couldnt understand this part: "Just make sure you pass the update function or setActiveStep as a prop to your components, so you could pass handleNext. And then in your form const handleFormSubmit = () => { // do something with formdata , props.handleNext() } – "

Comment: I defined button like you said like this: <Button
                        variant="contained"
                        color="primary"
                        onClick={handleNext}
                        className={classes.button}
                        form={`form-step${activeStep}`} 
                        value="Submit"
                      >
                        {activeStep === steps.length - 1 ? "Finish" : "Next"}
                      </Button> and I also defined the form id but I still couldnt get how to pass handleNext

Comment: you pass the props to the components here: <Typography>{getStepContent(index, {checkoutForm, handleChange, handleNext})}</Typography> . You then don't need the onClick={handleNext} on the button, but only type="submit"

Comment: I've updated my answer, so I hope it's more clear

Comment: Thank you very much for your clear answer. It is perfectly splendid.